# How often does a Windows 10 AD Client refresh it's DNS caches and how can I can control it?

Tags: domain-name-system, cache, windows-10

We had some DNS issues this morning and after they were fixed we were asked to apply

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

To refresh our local caches.

Some people got the changes automatically while others had to apply this. That got me wondering as where in Windows 10 this setting is controlled. Is it server controlled or does each client have it's own rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concur with Joeqwerty but would like to add you can check the length of the TTL of DNS records by running the command **ipconfig /displaydns**.  This will show all the dns records your machine has cached and how long it will keep it for.  If your machine has a lot of cached entries you can pipe the command to a txt file so you can search easily e.g. **ipconfig /displaydns > dnscache.txt**. If you keep running the command you should see the expire time in seconds decrease.

If your query is regarding DNS records that you set up in your own organisation than you can edit the TTL of the record.  Open DNS management and ensure you have have advanced view, go to a DNS record and you will see the TTL.  You can increase/decrease this to your liking assuming you are allowed to.

Answer (score 3):

DNS records cached in the local DNS cache are governed by the TTL of those records. The TTL is defined for those records in the DNS zone itself on the DNS server.

Comment: Although this answer is in theory correct, factually Windows cares crap. The W10 Enterprise Computer that I have access to generates ca. 1000 queries per day to mail.corp-name.com when its TTL is 86400.